# CommandButton to run on a specific worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I open a Form created in VBA which has a CommandButton that erases the row you have selected in a ListBox (which shows 6 columns from Sheet1) displayed in the same form .
I want to open the form from other worksheets (in this case Sheet5) but the code I have only works on the current worksheet (erasing the corresponding row on Sheet5). How can I write the code for the CommandButton to erase the row selected but on Sheet1?
This is the code I currently have:

```
Private Sub BotonBorrarP_Click()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    If ListaIngresos.Selected(i) Then
        Rows(i + 1).Select
        Selection.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate to change the context to another worksheet, then perform whatever actions necessary. Just be sure to change back to the relevant worksheet afterwards/as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the sheet directly:

```vb
Private Sub BotonBorrarP_Click()

    Dim i As Integer, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'step backwards when deleting rows!
    For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row - 1 to 1 step -1
        If ListaIngresos.Selected(i) Then
            ws.Rows(i + 1).Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used the code but after trying to use the button I got a runtime error '9', Subscript out of Range. How could I solve this?

Comment: Which line produced the error?

Comment: I'd guess there's no sheet named "Sheet1" in your workbook?

Comment: I had rename Sheet1 to something else. I wrote the correct name and it worked! Thanks a lot for the help!!